# How to add full calendar date to dynamic textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar, datetimepicker, fullcalendar-3

My textboxes are getting the value from calendar though I am using Class but still all the textboxes dates become's same.
I am adding new rows in my project and all rows contain datetime textbox
I have assign a class to that textbox
when I select the date in the second textbox the first textbox date also changed with it and it overwrite it with the second one and vice versa.

Following is my code to generate new row:-

```
 $(function () {
        $('#addNewRow').click(function () {
            //$(".datepick").datetimepicker("destroy");

            $('<tr id="tablerow' + counter + '">< >' +

                                 @*<tr class="editorRow">*@
                                            $('#LineDEtail').find("#tablerow0:first").html() +
                                            @*</tr>*@

                '</>' +
                '<td style="padding-bottom:5px !important;">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeTr(' + counter + ');" >Delete</button>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>').appendTo('#submissionTable');
            //$(".datepick").datetimepicker();
            clickmeforcalender();
            counter++;
            return false;

        });
    });
```

Following is my code for getting events which are saved in the calendar 
In this code I am defining the function to get value from full calendar. I have Emphasis that part.

```
 $(".datepick").click(function () {
        debugger


        $('#calendar').show();
        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Booking/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, a) {
                    events.push({
                        title: a.Function_Name,
                        start: a.Function_Date1,
                        url: a.Booking_ID
                        //Function_Slot:a.Function_Slot,
                        //Marquee_Name:a.Marquee_Name,
                        //Marquee_Slot: a.Marquee_Slot

                    });

                        $("#calendar").css("background-color", "WHITE");
                })

                GenerateCalender(events);
            },

            error: function (error) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });

        ***$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                $(".datepick").val(date.format())
            }
        });***

    });
```

**.datepick is the class name of my textbox**

Here is the textbox Code

```
 <td class="date col-sm-2">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Function_Date, new { @class = "date glyphicon glyphicon-calendar datepick", @id = "", @name = "date[]", @onclick = "clickmeforcalender();" })
</td>
```

Following is the code for GenerateCalender ()

```
 function GenerateCalender(events) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'addEventButton',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek',

        },
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        navLinks: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: events,



        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            selectedEvent = calEvent;
            //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
            jsEvent.preventDefault();

            $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
            var $description = $('<div/>');
            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));

            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.title));
            $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

            var temp = $('#myModal').modal();


        },


    });
}
```

Need quick help thanks

[image]

Comment: You didn't actually show the textbox code, but if all your date textboxes have the class `datepick` then `$(".datepick").val` will select all of them and update all of them. That's what a class selector does - it selects all elements with the same class. You need to find a way to uniquely identify the textbox you want. You haven't given us enough information for us to tell you a good way of doing that, but that's what you need to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the code, Added the text box code.
Still finding a way to uniquely identify my text boxes

Comment: What does the function `clickmeforcalender()` do? Because you already defined that click event on all your datepick fields, but then you also define `$(".datepick").click` as well, and then later within that you execute `clickmeforcalender();` again...so it's a bit confusing why you try to run that function twice.

Comment: Also, the more of this I see, the more it looks like you are trying to use fullCalendar just as a date picker?? That's not its job. If that's all you're Maybe you need [something like more like this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Got your point, I have commented the calling of clickmeforcalender().
Yes I am using full calendar as date picker, because I have saved some events in Full calendar.

Comment: Those two facts don't really tie together, for me. Must the user choose a date based on the location of existing events, or something?

Comment: If there is any event so FullCalendar will show it so user will not select that date

Comment: Ok. Another missing piece...what does the `GenerateCalender` function do?

Comment: GenerateCalender Is used to generate the FullCalendar, which is working fine.

Comment: No I meant can you show it please. Then I can fit everything together in my mind properly and maybe I can suggest a sensible solution

Comment: Code is updated sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code would make more sense rearranged like this:

The advantages are:

1) You only run the GetEvents AJAX function when it's actually needed, not every time you open the calendar

2) you don't keep re-creating the fullCalendar every time you click on a date field

3) You set a global variable representing the last clicked textbox, so that fullCalendar knows which one to populate when a date is clicked.

```
//create the calendar just once
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'addEventButton',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek',
    },
    navLinks: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
        $(currentDateField).val(date.format()); //set the value on the last clicked date field
    },
    //dynamic on-demand event feed - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function for details
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) { 
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Booking/GetEvents",
        success: function (data) {
            var events = [];
            $.each(data, function (i, a) {
                events.push({
                    title: a.Function_Name,
                    start: a.Function_Date1,
                    url: a.Booking_ID
                    //Function_Slot:a.Function_Slot,
                    //Marquee_Name:a.Marquee_Name,
                    //Marquee_Slot: a.Marquee_Slot
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('failed');
        }
      });
    },
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        selectedEvent = calEvent;
        //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        jsEvent.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
        var $description = $('<div/>');
        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.title));
        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);
        var temp = $('#myModal').modal();
    },
});

$("#calendar").hide();

var currentDateField = null; //to hold the last clicked date field

$(".datepick").click(function () {
  currentDateField = this; //assign the last clicked date field
  $('#calendar').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.